# Cannot display 3D model in threejs

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, gltf

I am trying to display a model which is gltf but it doesn't come up. I'm running of a http server as without so it is causing more errors now this "Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."  comes up

```
    <html><head>
<title>My first three.js app</title>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  canvas {
    display: block;
  }
</style></head>[enter image description here][1]<body>
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script src="js/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script> var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
  );var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load("LegoEv3.glb", handle_load);
  var mesh;

  function handle_load(gltf) {
    mesh = gltf.scene.children[0];
    scene.add(mesh);
    mesh.position, (z = -1000);
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
</script>
```

Comment: "I'm running of a http server as without" is hard to understand. Are you sure `mesh = gltf.scene.children[0]` is correct? You are rendering before the model is loaded, try putting another render call at the end of the `handle_load` function (so it renders again after the model loads and is added to the scene).

Comment: i dont understand can you give me more details

Comment: I added an answer so I could include a code example.

Answer (score 0):

you render only once before the model is loaded.
Try rendering again after the model is loaded and added to the scene

```
function handle_load(gltf) {
    mesh = gltf.scene.children[0];
    scene.add(mesh);
    mesh.position, (z = -1000);
    renderer.render(scene, camera); // You need to render after model is added
}
```

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/LegoRobot/ComplexRobot.glb' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. i have and this is the error i am getting now please note that i have changed my 3d model to another one

Comment: read [how to run things locally](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally)